# how to close parent window when colorbox is closed?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm loading colorbox on page load.

```
parent.$.fn.colorbox({href: "#inline_example1", overlayClose:false, inline:true,width:'80%',height:'90%', onClosed:function(){} ,onLoad: function() { }});
```

I want to close the parent window when the colorbox is closed.
Please tell me what should I write inside `onClosed` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear what parent is but try something like:

```
window.opener.close();
```

or

```
window.close();
```

or

```
window.parent.close();
```

I hope one of these would help!!

Answer (score -1):

In your onClosed handler, you could put:

```
window.close();
```